# Write pure string to file in python

Tags: python

I have `str = 'some words\n'` and i want to print it to file with

```
with open(newfile, 'a') as the_file:
    the_file.write(str)
```

how can i write literally just `'some words\n'` not `'some words'` with enter at the end?

Comment: You have to escape the backslash as a double backslash or use a raw string: `str = r'some words\n' `. BTW `str` is a bad choice for a variable name, it will mask the built-in `str` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the escape character:

```
str = 'some words\n'
with open(newfile, 'a') as the_file:
    str = str.replace("\n","\\n")
    the_file.write(str)
```

Comment: maybe you reconsider about variable naming. Naming a variable as `str` will change use of `str`'s default behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Please try doule back slash like `str = "some words \\n"` .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the raw-string `r'..'` construct to do that, also would be nice to use the file-open constructs within the `try` catch blocks and close the open file descriptor once the write is complete.

```
try:
    str = r'some words\n'
    with open('newfile', 'a') as fd:
        fd.write(str)
        fd.close()

except IOError as e:
    print('unable to open file newfile in append mode')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "some words\n"

with open("temp.txt", "w+") as fp:

        temp = string[:-2] + r'\n'

        fp.write(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the string representation without the quotes. It will work with all escape sequences, not only the '\n':

```
w = "some\twords\n"
repr(w)[1:-1] # some\twords\n
```

However there is an issue with quotes:

```
w = '''single'double"quote'''
repr(w)[1:-1] # single\'double"quote
```