# Python, how to write string and function to text

Tags: python

I'm new to Python so apologies if this is a basic mistake, I'm trying to write certain information to a txt file (OS is windows).

I want to write "Platform architecture:" as text, and write the output of platform.architecture to a file. Here is my current code:

```
import.platform
file = open('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pc info.txt','w')

file.write('Platform architecture:'),platform.architecture
```

When I hit run a file named pc info is generated on my desktop as expected, but in the file only `Platform architecture:` is produced as text.
It seems `file. write platform.architecture()` isn't writing any information to the txt file?

Any ideas please?

Comment: Use `with` for file handling

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python write string of bytes to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349918/python-write-string-of-bytes-to-file)

Comment: See also SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48003241/8928024).

Comment: The fact that you didn't *call* the `platform.architecture` function and that it isn't even *inside* the parentheses of `file.write(...)` tells me that you haven't grokked functions yet, and explaining how functions work really isn't what SO is for. It looks to me like you need to spend some time with a programming tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Debugging**:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax on line 1

```
import.platform
```

Should have been:

```
import platform
```

You should have called the `platform.architecture()` while writing to the file.

```
file.write('Platform architecture:'),platform.architecture
```

Should have been:

```
file.write('Platform architectue: {}'.format(platform.architecture()))
```

**Hence**:

Using [`str.format()`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3):

```
import platform
print(platform.architecture())   # ('64bit', 'WindowsPE') (in my case)

logFile = 'Path\\to\\your\\file'    
with open(logFile, 'w') as f:
    f.write('Platform architectue: {}'.format(platform.architecture()))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Platform architectue: ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

Comment: @MrShaun you may edit the question if it is relevant to the current question, otherwise ask a new question. PS. if this answer helped you may accept it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
import platform
with open('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pc_info.txt','w') as file:
    file.write('Platform architecture: {}'.format(platform.architecture()))
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation, especially as OP is new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
# importing the platform module from the site-packages in python 
import platform 

# adding the file absolute path with name, so you can run the script anywhere
# in you system

file_path =r'C:\Users\user\file.txt'

"""
   creating the file at given path with the write permission,
   using with instead of directly open. (why go here to 
   know -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334061/file-read-using-open-vs-with-open
"""

with open(file_path,'w+') as file:        
    file.write('Platform architecture : {}'.format(platform.architecture()))
    """
       writing the output of platform.architecture() command in the file.
       using `str.format()` function for better readablity.
    """
```

Comment: Please explain *why* this is the solution?

Comment: @Machavity hope the future readers can now find it easy to understand code that i have written